# compiling a java program with a package containing a file from a different directory

Tags: java, compilation, directory, package

I have a packaged java program in one directory that wants to import a class from a different directory, but it won't compile.  I am trying to compile it from the command in so I can understand what is going on, so I don't want to use an IDE just yet.  I've tried every permutation of specifying the classpath on the javac line, but the compiler refuses to find the main packaged java program.  I believe this to be a simple task, but I can't figure it out.  I've researched the internet and some books, but all I can find is basic compilation instructions and compilation instructions when all classes are located in the same directory.  So that has been zero help.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Can you provide 1- The directory structures involved; 2- The permutations you have tried

Answer (score 0):

You can compile multiple .java files at the same time, even if they are in different folders.

For example, if this were your files:

```
Project
   - Folder1
        - File1.java
   - Folder2
        - File2.java
```

Then go to the Project folder and execute the following command.

On Windows:

```
javac.exe Folder1\File1.java Folder2\File2.java
```

On OSX/Linux:

```
javac Folder1/File1.java Folder2/File2.java
```

But as your project becomes larger and starts including more dependencies, you should consider using [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Gradle](https://gradle.org/), which are tools that make your life easier when you compile Java projects with many files, dependencies and/or complex folder structures.